# Conditional if issue in php apache server

Tags: php, if-statement, xampp, conditional-statements

I am working on (Localhost) XAMPP Server 3.2.1

This is php file MyAjax.php:

```
<?php
    $data = isset($_REQUEST['data']);

    if($data == "logout")
    {
        echo "<br />inside logout";
    }
    else if($data == "getReminder")
    {
        echo "<br />inside getReminder";
    }
?>
```

Output of following url should be `inside getReminder`

```
http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/TimeTable/PHP_Code/MyAjax.php?data=getReminder
```

And Output of following url should be `inside logout`

```
http://127.0.0.1/dashboard/TimeTable/PHP_Code/MyAjax.php?data=logout
```

But both URLs are returning the same output `inside logout`.

Please help me what is wrong in this?

Comment: `isset()` returns a _boolean_. That means `$data` can _never_ be "logout" or whatever. A simple look into the documentation would have told you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should read URL string parameters as follow:

```
$data = $_REQUEST['data'];
```

so your code should be:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {
        $data = $_REQUEST['data'];

        if ($data == "logout") {
            echo "<br />inside logout";
        } else if ($data == "getReminder") {
            echo "<br />inside getReminder";
        }
    }
?>
```